# Verify SSL Error with Golang http server?

Tags: go, ssl

I have a golang project that provides some REST API endpoints over SSL.  I serve things over https with this line of code:

```
router := mux.NewRouter() // mux is from the gorilla mux library

headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"Accept","Accept-Encoding","Content-Length","Content-Type",
  "Authorization","Organization"})
originsOk := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
methodsOk := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"})


http.ListenAndServeTLS(":8000", "path/to/example.cert","path/to/example.com.key",handlers.CORS(originsOk, headersOk, methodsOk)(router)
```

When I visit `https://example.com:8000/some-endpoint` with a web browser, everything loads up fine and I see a nice green lock icon in my address bar.  But when I try to connect to it with Postman software, Postman just says it can't get any response unless I disable "Verify SSL" in the settings.

Is there something wrong with the way I initialize my golang http server?

**Edit**
The certificate I'm using is a commercial certificate verified by Sectigo Limited that supports wild card subdomains.  This API end point is actually in production usage and other people with ReactJS and Angular JS apps have successfully been consuming data from these end points.

**Edit 2**
I reviewed my certificates.  I have several files.  My `/path/to/example.cert` is actually a concatenation of these files:

- example.com.ca-bundle
- example.com.crt
- example.com.csr
- example.com.key

Between the each cert in the `/path/to/example.cert`, I do see something like:

```
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----^@^@^@^@^@^@.....example.com.key^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@....-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I'm not sure if those `^@^@^@^@^@` characters should be there?  I tried removing them and restarting my golang http server, but it didn't make any difference.

When I tried to test my `https://example.com:8000` at [ssl labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/), it said port 8000 is not supported.  Most of REST APIs are hosted on the same domain but with different port numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately the limited amount of detail you provide is not sufficient to answer your question. It might be that you are using a self-signed certificate and explicitly accepted it as trusted in the browser or imported it but that you did nothing like this for Postman. It might be that you are using a public certificate which should be trusted by Postman too but that you've failed to provide the necessary chain certificates - browser often work around this problem but other applications don't.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I updated my question some more.  I'm curious to learn what would typically be needed in teh chain of certificates?  If I recall, my process was create a CSR and Key, get CSR signed/approved by Sectigo, get a CRT file back.  I think that was my process...

Comment: You usually do not get only the signed leaf certificate back but also any intermediate certificates. These MUST be provided to the client too so that it can build the trust chain to the local root certificate. See [SSL Certificate framework 101: How does the browser actually verify the validity of a given server certificate?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/ssl-certificate-framework-101-how-does-the-browser-actually-verify-the-validity) for more details on how certificate validation works.

Comment: A valid chain consists of all certificates from the leaf up to but excluding the root certificate. You can check your configuration over at ssllabs: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ If it mentions "extra download" you're missing an intermediate.

Comment: Very helpful links!  I've updated my question to say my `example.cert` seems to be a concatenation of several files, and that ssllabs.com doesn't seem to work on port 8001.